# Can I use Chef-Solo to provision a server created with knife-eucalyptus

Tags: chef-infra, knife, chef-solo, eucalyptus, knife-solo

I am able to create a new server using knife-eucalyptus like so:

```
knife euca server create
```

The server gets created but provisioning fails with the following message:

```
"ERROR: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /etc/chef/validation.pem"
```

This is understandable as I presume it is trying to use Chef Server for provisioning. This is the problem. I want to use Chef Solo to provision this server (at least for now).

Is there some way to instruct knife-eucalyptus to provision new servers with Chef Solo?

Comment: Just remembered that stackoverflow doesn't really like these types of questions.

So I re-asked it on serverfault:
http://serverfault.com/questions/578991/can-i-use-chef-solo-to-provision-a-server-created-with-knife-eucalyptus

Answer (score 0):

I put in a patch to Knife EC2 that lets it work with Eucalyptus:
    https://github.com/viglesiasce/knife-ec2

I have used this to provision and maintain running instances without issues over the last few months. I need to submit the PR soon to get it into mainline.

Configuration required is the following in knife.rb:

```
knife[:region] = 'eucalyptus'
knife[:endpoint] = ENV['EC2_URL']
knife[:aws_access_key_id] = ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY']
knife[:aws_secret_access_key] = ENV['AWS_SECRET_KEY']
```

Then you can source your Eucalyptus credentials and start deploying with "knife ec2 create".

Edit:
I commented on the original pull request here:
https://github.com/opscode/knife-ec2/pull/134

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer but it isn't exactly answering my question. I have gotten the knife-eucalyptus plugin to work so I don't really have to change that. Although it's good to know that knife-ec2 is supposed to support different endpoints. I'll try that out sometime.
But my question was answered on ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/578991/can-i-use-chef-solo-to-provision-a-server-created-with-knife-eucalyptus/